# Unable to find signingReport for SHA-1 fingerprint key in Gradle Bar : Android Studio Hedgehog

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, sha1

This is my GradleBar in Android Studio (version: hedgehog)

[image]

I want to get a SHA-1 key fingerprint from my Android Studio for Firebase.
Example of how I want signingReport file in my gradle bar -> Tasks dropdown.

This is the example of how:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In most of the recent Android studios, you can't able to see that. [image]if is not there no problem you have multiple ways to do that.please find attachment below